# How to get whole month or week or day level data in a single query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have  a data in which I have to display a record by month or week or day according to the date selected.

```
If the date selected is for a whole month for like january its 01-01-2015 to 31-01-2015

then it should fetch for the record for the whole month.
```

If the date selected is such that for example like `01-01-2015` to `15-02-2015`. Now here there are more than a month but `Feburary` is not in whole month so the `januar`y will record will come in one and next first week record for `Feburary` will be fetched in one and next week record will be fetched in another`.

Also he day left (as there will be 14 days in week two) will have a another record.`

So, in all `4 record` will be fetched. Here instead of fecthing whole 46 days record I am just fecthing 4 records. Hope I gave a proper example if you can't just comment I will explain with another exapmle. I am now just worrying about how to split month, week and day. Can anyone help me with that. Thanks in advance

I am only worried about how to split the dates in month week or a day. The formula is simple if e have whole month the entry should be shown in a single record. If we date between of more than week it should shown week wise and less than week it should be on day level

Input
Here Time_type_id is a foreign key from other 3 tables. This time_type_id will help to get data day, week or month wise. The data is shown according to date passed by the user. Time_id is the primary key of the table and it points to the id of other 3 fact table.

```
Dimesion Table
Time_type_id                Time_id                  metric_id                  
    1                                     1                            100 
    1                                     2                            400
    1                                     3                            300
    1                                     4                            100 
    1                                     5                            250
    2                                     6                            1000
    2                                     7                            2000
    2                                     8                            3000
    2                                     9                            2000
    2                                    10                           5000
    3                                    11                           11000
    3                                    12                           20000
    3                                    13                           40000
    3                                    14                           50000
    3                                    15                           60000

Fact table

Fact1- This shows the day basis data.

 Dim_type                         Id                            day_date                    month                           year
    1                              1                            01-09-2015                September                         2015
    1                              2                           02-09-2015                September                         2015
    1                              3                            03-09-2015                September                         2015
    1                              4                            04-09-2015                September                         2015        
    1                              5                            05-09-2015                September                         2015


Fact2- This shows the weekly basis data.

Dim_type                          Id                           week_number                   month                     year
    2                              6                               week1                    September                      2015
    2                              7                               week2                    September                      2015
    2                              8                               week3                    September                      2015
    2                              9                                  week4                    September                      2015         
    2                              10                              week1                     October                       2015

Fact3- This shows the monthly basis data.

Dim_type                         Id                                       month                     year
    3                            11                                   September                  2015
    3                            12                                  September                  2015
    3                            13                                  September                  2015
    3                            14                                  September                  2015         
    3                            15                                   October                    2015
```

Now the user just passed the dates between which he wants to see the data and according to dates passed we have to sho the ouput.
If it is month level we have to show Fact3 table where Dim_type is 3 same for other two table. I just want how to split the the date

Output-

For second example-

```
  Sr no      id                         data (from the date range)
    1         1                          data from whole January
    2         2                          data from first week of Feburary
    3         3                          data from second week of Feburary
    4         4                          data from 15 Febuaray
```

Note: Don't make that a week will always have 7 days maybe if week start from Thrusday than it would not have 7 days

Comment: post an example of the expected output with a sample of data. you want the output by week, by month or 'it depends'? it depends on what?

Comment: added the output...please read question again

Comment: ok, now please provide the input data you work on to produce that output. it would be way easier should you follow the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking.

Comment: sorry from next time I will be cautions...I have added my input

Answer (score 0):

you can use two parameter, so it's dynamic to choose dates like:

```
Declare @FromDate DATETIME,
        @ToDate DATETIME

SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE DATE BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
```

Comment: its not giving any output also not asking for date input

Answer (score 0):

There can be two solution available in your case:

**Solution # 1**

You need a table/temptable which contains data for all dates with columns like Date, DaySrNo, WeekSrNo, MonthSrNo and Moreover YearSrNo. Use this table in Join and get your data among three tables (which are also in JOIN)

**Solution # 2**
You need extra column for date range in your existing table structure:
like In Fact1 table contains day wise data, So you need Date Range Columns Like StartDate and EndDate 
Same way Same Two column in other tables Fact2 and Fact3

So using this column in Join and where filter you can get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('IAS_TEST_SCHEMA.DATESPLIT', 'P') IS NOT NULL
  DROP PROCEDURE IAS_TEST_SCHEMA.DATESPLIT;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE IAS_TEST_SCHEMA.DATESPLIT (@STARTDATE date, @ENDDATE date)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @DATEDIFF integer,
          @MONTHEND integer = 0,
          @MONTHSTART integer = 0,
          @STARTWEEK integer = 0,
          @ENDWEEK integer = 0;

  IF @STARTDATE = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, 0, @STARTDATE), 0))
  BEGIN
    SET @MONTHSTART = 1;
  END
  IF MONTH(@ENDDATE) != MONTH(DATEADD(DAY, 1, @ENDDATE))
  BEGIN
    SET @MONTHEND = 1;
  END
  IF DATEPART(DW, @STARTDATE) = 2
  BEGIN
    SET @STARTWEEK = 1;
  END
  IF DATEPART(DW, @ENDDATE) = 1
  BEGIN
    SET @ENDWEEK = 1;
  END
  SET @DATEDIFF = DATEDIFF(DAY, @STARTDATE, @ENDDATE);
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN @DATEDIFF <= 30 THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0)))
      WHEN @DATEDIFF > 30 AND
        @DATEDIFF < 90 THEN CASE
          WHEN @STARTWEEK = 1 THEN 'WEEK ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0)))
            - DATEPART(WEEK, DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0))) +
            '/' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0))) + '/' + '1') AS nvarchar) +
            ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0)))
          ELSE CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0)))
        END
      WHEN @DATEDIFF >= 90 THEN CASE
          WHEN @MONTHSTART = 1 THEN DATENAME(MONTH, @STARTDATE) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, @STARTDATE)
          ELSE CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0)))
        END
    END AS START_DATE,
    CASE
      WHEN @DATEDIFF <= 30 THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0)))
      WHEN @DATEDIFF > 30 AND
        @DATEDIFF < 90 THEN CASE
          WHEN @STARTWEEK = 1 THEN CASE
              WHEN @ENDWEEK = 1 THEN 'WEEK ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0)))
                - DATEPART(WEEK, DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0))) +
                '/' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0))) + '/' + '1') AS nvarchar) +
                ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0)))
              ELSE 'WEEK ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @ENDDATE), -1)))
                - DATEPART(WEEK, DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @ENDDATE), -1))) + '/'
                + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @ENDDATE), -1))) + '/' + '1') AS nvarchar) +
                ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @ENDDATE), -1)))
            END
          ELSE CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @STARTDATE), 6)))
        END
      WHEN @DATEDIFF >= 90 THEN CASE
          WHEN @MONTHSTART = 1 THEN CASE
              WHEN @MONTHEND = 0 THEN DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @ENDDATE) - 1, -1)) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @ENDDATE) - 1, -1))
              ELSE DATENAME(MONTH, @ENDDATE) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, @ENDDATE)
            END
          ELSE CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(S, -1, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(M, 0, @STARTDATE) + 1, 0))))
        END
    END AS END_DATE
  UNION
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN @DATEDIFF <= 30 THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0)))
      WHEN @DATEDIFF > 30 AND
        @DATEDIFF < 90 THEN CASE
          WHEN @STARTWEEK = 1 THEN 'WEEK ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0)))
            - DATEPART(WEEK, DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0))) +
            '/' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0))) + '/' + '1') AS nvarchar) +
            ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0)))
          ELSE 'WEEK ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 7)))
            - DATEPART(WEEK, DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 7))) +
            '/' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 7))) + '/' + '1') AS nvarchar) +
            ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 7)))
        END
      WHEN @DATEDIFF >= 90 THEN CASE
          WHEN @MONTHSTART = 1 THEN DATENAME(MONTH, @STARTDATE) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, @STARTDATE)
          ELSE DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, -1, @STARTDATE), 0))) + ' '
            + DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, -1, @STARTDATE), 0)))
        END
    END,
    CASE
      WHEN @DATEDIFF <= 30 THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0)))

      WHEN @DATEDIFF > 30 AND
        @DATEDIFF < 90 THEN CASE
          WHEN @ENDWEEK = 1 THEN 'WEEK ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0)))
            - DATEPART(WEEK, DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0))) +
            '/' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0))) + '/' + '1') AS nvarchar) +
            ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0)))
          ELSE 'WEEK ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @ENDDATE), -1)))
            - DATEPART(WEEK, DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @ENDDATE), -1))) + '/'
            + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @ENDDATE), -1))) + '/' + '1') AS nvarchar) +
            ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @ENDDATE), -1)))
        END
      WHEN @DATEDIFF > 90 THEN CASE
          WHEN @MONTHEND = 0 THEN DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @ENDDATE) - 1, -1))) + ' '
            + DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @ENDDATE) - 1, -1)))
          ELSE DATENAME(MONTH, @ENDDATE) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, @ENDDATE)
        END
    END
  UNION
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN @DATEDIFF <= 30 THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0)))
      WHEN @DATEDIFF > 30 AND
        @DATEDIFF < 90 THEN CASE
          WHEN @ENDWEEK = 1 THEN CASE
              WHEN @STARTWEEK = 1 THEN 'WEEK ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0)))
                - DATEPART(WEEK, DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0))) +
                '/' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0))) + '/' + '1') AS nvarchar) +
                ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 0)))
              ELSE 'WEEK ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 7)))
                - DATEPART(WEEK, DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 7))) +
                '/' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 7))) + '/' + '1') AS nvarchar) +
                ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), 7)))
            END
          ELSE CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @ENDDATE), -0)))
        END
      WHEN @DATEDIFF >= 90 THEN CASE
          WHEN @MONTHEND = 1 THEN DATENAME(MONTH, @STARTDATE) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, @STARTDATE)
          ELSE CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DD, -(DAY(@ENDDATE) - 1), @ENDDATE)))
        END
    END,
    CASE
      WHEN @DATEDIFF <= 30 THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0)))
      WHEN @DATEDIFF > 30 AND
        @DATEDIFF < 90 THEN CASE
          WHEN @ENDWEEK = 1 THEN 'WEEK ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0)))
            - DATEPART(WEEK, DATENAME(YEAR, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0))) +
            '/' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0))) + '/' + '1') AS nvarchar) +
            ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0)))
          ELSE CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0)))
        END
      WHEN @DATEDIFF >= 90 THEN CASE
          WHEN @MONTHEND = 1 THEN DATENAME(MONTH, @ENDDATE) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, @ENDDATE)
          ELSE CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ENDDATE), 0)))
        END
    END
END;
```

GO